# How do I get all the links on a web page using requests-html

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am new to web parsing and want to make a program that gets all the internal and external links on a web page and I have no idea how to do this at all and all I have written is this

```
from requests_html import *

sss = HTMLSession()
k = sss.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki')
hhh = HTML(html=k.html.html)
print(hhh.find('href'))
```

I don't know why it prints [] when the href tags are everywhere 
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check the documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#tutorial-usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all the internal and external links using the code below. The code converts all relative links to absolute links.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
sss = HTMLSession()
k = sss.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki')
links = k.html.absolute_links
print(links)
```

Comment: you don't need base_url as you are writting the url inside get()